# OCC Search API results-> products are not in same order everytime

Tags: search, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

We are facing a strange issue on Spartacus category page. Every time the same category page gets loaded, the products in the search results are not in the same order. Those products are coming up in the occ search api response in two different orders intermittently. What could be the reason for this?

Thanks

The issue is only in the production environment and not in the staging environment. There should be some configuration mismatch between the two environments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.